# How many users i can launch in Gatling with these computer parameters:

Tags: performance, testing, load, gatling, scala-gatling

I need to execute load test for our website with load 2000r/s,
what would you say about this according to my computer power, is that ok or not.

My Computer: 
MAC OS Version: 10.12.6 
Processor: 2.6 GHz Intel Core i5 
Memory: 8 GB 1600 MHz DDR3

Comment: How about trying it out?

Comment: looking at these 'tons' of comments I see I will